# How to fix WPF error: "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"?

Tags: c#, wpf

Suddenly my whole project stopped compiling at all, showing the following message:

> Program 'path_to_obj_project_folder' does not contain a static 'Main'
> method suitable for an entry point

I made no changes to project properties, just added some classes, moved some other classes into folders. Its an WPF Application project so it should be all OK. Entry point is where it should be, file App.xaml was not modified at all :(

What should I do to make it work again?

**NOTE**
*For reference*: if renaming the `App.xaml` this can happen. As OP stated, `App.xaml` was not altered; however, this is added for anyone that does rename the `App.xaml`.

Answer (score 477, accepted):

Check the properties of *App.xaml*. Is the `Build Action` still `ApplicationDefinition`?

Comment: Thanks, that partially fixed the problem. I had copied all file from an old project to a new `Windows Store App` project, and the `Build Action` was set to `Page` instead of `ApplicationDefinition`. I switched back to `ApplicationDefinition`, but I also had to delete the folder `obj\Debug`.

Comment: +1: Awesome! Truly a lifesaver. I was just about to create a new project and copy everything, but this did the trick. What have I learned: Don't mess with App.xaml... It bites.

Comment: I also had to manually delete obj\Debug; RebuildAll didn't fix it, no idea why...

Comment: Same problem in a VS 2017 UWP application. The build was for `Page` rather than `ApplicationDefinition`

Comment: `Build Action` switches to `Page` when you exclude and re-include the App.xaml file

Answer (score 45):

Maybe the "Output type" in properties->Application of the project must be a "Class Library" instead of console or windows application.

Comment: When using a CLI compiler the _Class Library_ output type can be specified by a `-t:library` argument.

Comment: Then why does that produce a `Library project file cannot specify ApplicationDefinition element.` error?

Answer (score 22):

Just in case anyone is having the same problem... I was getting this error, and it turned out to be my `<Application.Resources>` in my App.xaml file.  I had a resource outside my resource dictionary tags, and that caused this error.

Comment: I had a slightly different variation. I had empty Application.Resources tags and removing those fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

In my case (after renaming application namespace manually) I had to reselect the Startup object in Project properties.

Answer (score 6):

#### How to check build action

As per Kent Boogaart's answer,

- Check your `App.xaml` properties:
- Ensure the `Build Action` is `ApplicationDefinition`

#### How do I check?

See the Giphy I recorded below:

[image: See the giphy I recorded]

Comment: This fixed it for me.  I referenced (link) the App.xaml from another project and by default it was set to "Page".  Setting it to "ApplicationDefinition" fixed it.  Thank you! (Visual Studio 2022, C# WPF, .Net Framework 4.7.2)

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to get this kind of error when working on WPF/UPF application and in your project's **.csproj** uses wrong SDK i.e `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` instead of `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">`

Comment: If your file is already selected as `ApplicationDefinition` then try out this answer. This was the first answer of 100s on SO that /actually/ worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can also run into this if you're working on a WPF project that was started in VS 2010 (Beta 1), then moved into VS 2008.

Under the project properties, the .NET framework version gets unset (since .NET 4.0 isn't valid in VS 2008), and for some reason that causes this error.

If you set the .NET framework (e.g. to .NET 3.5), the error goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is still getting the same error, even with all the help above: I had this problem, I tried all the solutions given here, and I just found out that my problem was actually another error from my error list (which was about a missing image set to be my splash screen. i just changed its path to the right one and then all started to work)

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same error but then I found out that I typed small m instead of capital M in Main method

Comment: Yeah, forgot that it's case sensitive. Thanks!

Comment: Rather see, if your application's "property" has been defined a default startup project/class correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538404/

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the  problem while changing .net framework v4.7.2 to .net core 3.1,
and solved by adding

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>   
</PropertyGroup>
```

in `.csproj`

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error message when App.xaml (left-click) Properties/BuildAction was set to Page. Setting it to ApplicationDefinition solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Project Properties \ Output file -> Select Class Library  :)

Answer (score 0):

As what, I guess pixparker wanted to say, but remained to be not clear enough, for me at least, do ensure that... **All "Other Projects"** have an **"Output Type"** of **"Class Library"** selected while...
**Only "One Project"** being selected as either **"Window Application"** or **"Console Application"** output.