# Could not find 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Program' specified for Main method after renaming name space

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

I have a C# app that had the default namespace `WindowsFormsApplication1`.

I decided that I would like to use a different namespace so I renamed `WindowsFormsApplication1`. Now when I compile I get the error:

> Could not find 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Program' specified for Main
>   method.

To rename the namespace I highlighted the namespace in a file and hit F2.

How do I resolve this and change the actual namespace through out the project?

I am using Visual C# 2010 Express.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

In project -> properties change "startup object" to the new namespace.

[image: Select Startup Object]

Comment: If you happen to be in VS2017 for Mac, the same issue anwer is Project- Options -> Build -> General -> Code Generation -> Main Class. It needs the namespace and the .Program class name

Answer (score 4):

You should rename through the "Refаctor" feature of Visual Studio.

Comment: i did a recfactor like this and still had the same issue

Answer (score 1):

As Mausimo says you need to select the 'Startup object' in Project -> References, however I was finding that the new namespace was not being shown here; I could only select the old namespace or '(Not set)'. If you find the same then it appears VS (this is on 2013) does not pick up the change immediately, restart VS and you can then select the class under the new namespace.