# How to Create (.exe) in Windows from application from Console application Visual C# 2012

Tags: c#

I am new to programming, I am a Mechanical Engineer. Can anyone help show me how to Debug a Console Application

For example:

When i debug a program it gives the following error : (Rep is my file name)

```
Rep.exe doesn't contain a Static 'Main' Method suitable for an entry point
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Program does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for entry point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067063/program-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-for-entry-point)

Answer (score 2):

Show your code. Your main should have one String[] parameter, be static and return nothing. And maybe public or internal (but I'm not sure about this).

Something like this:

```
class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
         //... your code....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are coming from ConsoleApplication
add a class called `Program` and it looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YourNameSpace //<-------------------
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new YourForm()); //<----------------------
        }
    }
}
```

i think this will solve your problem :)
Yaser

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a static Main method in your class. Something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a ["How to: Create a C# Console Application"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wc2kk78%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in the msdn. Maybe you should start with it.

You should have something like this into your code :

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main() // dont forget the static
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello world"); // just print "hello world"
        Console.ReadLine(); // wait a key press before closing
    }
}
```