# c# WPF can't set startup

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, startup

I have project in WPF.

The problem is, when I move App.xaml file to subfolder, it doesn't want to compile because it can't find main method.

How to force Project to start application with window set in App.xaml file as StartUp Window?

I use Visual Studio 2010 express.

edit:

My App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="TraceabilityLoader.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="View/VmainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Subfolders in project:

View, Model, ViewModel etc....

Comment: Post please your App.xaml and your folder structure.

Comment: What's the reason you want to move app.xaml? As it's responsible for main there shouldn't be any reasonable argument against keeping it in the root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolve this issue with custom Startup Window using OnStartup:
App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Pin.Visualisation.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="OnStartup">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
namespace Pin.Visualisation
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var view = new MainWindow();
            view.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

My MainWindow stores in View/MainWindow. Is it useful for you?

Comment: Still error:
"program does not have a suitable static main method for an entry point"

Comment: Did you create WPF project in VS or did you create empty project?

Comment: I found same issue in WPF already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577298/program-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-for-an-entry-point. Is it usefull?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found resolution for my problem.
After moving App.xaml to other folder visual studio's changed Build Action from application definition to Page.
Changing it back solves problem.

Answer (score 0):

The class containing your main method (`App.xaml`, `App.xaml.cs`) have to be in the root of your startup project for them to be automatically detected.

If you want them in a sub folder, you have to manually specify the startup object:

1. Right click project
2. Navigate to the Application settings tab
3. Select from the startup object dropdown.

By convention, your startup object really should be in the root.

Comment: I have empty startup list. I can't select anything.

Comment: The startup object may just need to be in the root to be detected _at all_. You might have to suck it up and leave the `App.xaml` in the root.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna move the App.xaml to a subfolder because you wanna organize the structure. You can just leave the namespace to your first level.

```
namespace WpfApplication3 <-----
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
    }
}
```

If not you have to do as @Gusdor

Comment: Doesn't work for me.
Namespace to first level or not doesn't fix the error.
In startup dropdown list I have only 'Not Set'.