# Does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make some library software (For an assignment), but keep getting this error, Despite it working 20min before.

I did originally make this from a Windows Form Application, but do not know what went wrong :(

I have a feeling that this is a "simple" error to fix. But its answer still alludes me.

```
Program k:\LibrarySoftware\Library_Software\Library_Software\obj\Debug\Library_Software.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point




Library.cs 

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Library_Software
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form 
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lblYear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnAddBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Application.OpenForms["Add_Book"] != null)
            { 
                //you can use closing or hiding method
                Application.OpenForms["Add_Book"].Close();
                //Application.OPenForms["Add_Book"].Hide();
            }

            Add_Book B = new Add_Book();
            B.Show();

        }

        private void lblNarrator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void cbxBookType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void btnLoadBooks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnDeleteBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Application.OpenForms["Form2"] != null)
            {
                //you can use closing or hiding method
                Application.OpenForms["Form2"].Close();
                //Application.OPenForms["Add_Book"].Hide();
            }

            Form2 D = new Form2();
            D.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

*Also if there are any other errors please point them out*

Comment: Have you created project in visual studio?
If yes, what kind of project was it? Do you have any other file in this project?

Comment: Seems like the compiler is expecting a static Main method, so I suspect this is a Console application, not a WinForms application. Your using statements also hint at this; using System.Windows.Forms looks like it was added last and manually. Don't know how you got to this point though.

Comment: What is your `Program.cs` file content? It should have method `Main` which runs main application form.

Comment: Can you try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16551083/125740 and see if it makes it work.

Comment: @JohnWillemse it id a Windows Form Application. and I can not code very well so i attempt to use snippets of code from old my assignments.

Comment: @Dzior It is Visual studio. There is a Add_Book.cs and Delete_Book.cs running alongside.

Comment: Do you have a `Program.cs` file in your project? If so, please add it's contents to your question. If not, see hSchroedl's answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577298/program-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-for-an-entry-point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your form file into `WindowsFormsApplication` project.

In your visual studio:
 - Go to File -> New Project
 - Search for `Windows Forms Application`
 - Fill the textboxes and click Finish

Now you can hit F5 to start the application and eventually add your library form to solution

Comment: I think this is the best idea. Just delete it and start again.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a main method in your project. The form does not initialize itself, it must be initialized in a method which acts as an entry point for your application. 
Creating a new winforms project in VS2012 yields this class:

```
    static class Program {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

If you do not have a class file "Program.cs" in your project  create one and add the code I just provided. The application should then run as expected. 
My guess is you deleted the class by accident or something like that.

Comment: Where do I put this within my code - it seems where-ever i place it, errors

Comment: Good explanation by hSchroedi, to add in his answer, you can follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607702/does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-for-an-entry-point/16551083#16551083

Comment: @Yahya: Yeh, saw your comment a tad too late. Thanks for adding that!

Comment: @mcclma Please specify which errors those are? Do you import the necessary libraries, e.g. System and System.Windows.Forms?

Comment: @Yahya tried this, but i don't need  new .cs file. I need the designer view to still work, and all that did was break it and add errors.

Comment: @mcclma Form1 is just a class (with some UI logic), how would you instantiate it?

Comment: @Yahya I dont fully understand programming - its been a while.