# The name "X" does not exist in the namespace "using:Y"

Tags: c#, xaml, namespaces, visual-studio-2015, uwp

After reading every article here and trying every suggested action I'm out of things to try:

I have a namespace issue in Visual Studio 2015 - in a XAML file in UWP.
The concrete error message is:

> "The name "FieldManagementViewModel" does not exist in the namespace
>   "using:StudyConfigurationClient.ViewModels"".

This is my XAML:
[image: XAML.]

This is the structure to show, that the folder and file actually exists, folder structure equals namespaces in this project:

[image: structure.]

I've looked all references and namespaces through, I've repaired Visual Studio 2015, I've cleaned and rebuilt several times and changed platform for the build back and forth - I'm out of options.

Comment: What is in the `FieldManagementViewModel.cs` file? Is the class in there called `FieldManagementViewModel` and is it marked as `public` and in the same namespace `Y`?

Comment: ViewModel is a folder, not a namespace.

Comment: The class is called FieldManagementViewModel, it is public and it resides in the namespace "StudyConfigurationClient.ViewModels" - the namespaces are equal to the folder structure.
The XAML file itself is residing in "StudyConfigurationClient.Views.CreateStudy" if that helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for helping - this issue magically went away when I pulled a change from git, which shouldn't affect this in any way. Sorry for not being able to help others, but I haven't got a clue about what happened.

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me:

1. Remove the problematic XAML tag, so that solution will build
2. Rebuild project
3. Restore the tag

I think VS falls into a chicken & egg situation here, in that it needs newly added classes built so that XAML can see them, but it can't build them because XAML can't see them.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this solution to this probelm:
- Close and re-open Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem occurred in App.xaml. In the properties for App.xaml the `BuildAction` had somehow been changed to `Page`. After restoring the `BuildAction` to `ApplicationDefinition` the problem went away. (See also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577298/program-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-for-an-entry-point).)