# my Automation code : program does not contain a static main method suitable for an entry point when i'm working C# with selenium web driver

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests

In C# Selenium web driver script I'm getting an error.

Here is my C# Selenium web driver code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace UnitTestProject3
{
    [TestClass]
    public class testrammi
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void SetupDllTest()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("docs.seleniumhq.org /download/");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my code: using System;
     using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
     using OpenQA.Selenium;
     using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

       namespace UnitTestProject3
        {`enter code here`
         [TestClass]
           public class testrammi
             {
               [TestMethod]
               public void SetupDllTest()
                 {
                  IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://docs.seleniumhq.org  /download/");
                  }
             }
        }`

Comment: What error are you getting? The wording could help.

Comment: Just read the question title, try the solutions [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577298/program-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-for-an-entry-point).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it works for me

```
    using System;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;


    namespace UnitTestProject3
    {
        class Program
        {
            public static dynamic True { get; private set; }

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                SetupDllTest();
            }

            static void SetupDllTest()
            {
                // Your code here
```