# Program * does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point* with code

Tags: c#, oop

I've had the homework of making a program, made up of 2 seperate projects, containing classes for a Square, Rectangle, and a Parallelepiped, and to be able to calculate their areas. I think I've done everything correctly and connected the projects, but I keep getting this error message when I try to compile the code:

Program * does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point.

Both of my projects have Static Main methods.

**First Project**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace zad8
{
    public abstract class CFormulas
    {
        abstract public double S();
        abstract public double P();
        abstract public double SF();
        abstract public double V();
    }
    public class CSquare : CFormulas
    {
        double a { get; set; }
        public CSquare(double a)
        { this.a = a; }
        public override double S() { return a * a; }
        public override double P() { return 4 * a; }

    }
   public class CRectangular : CFormulas
    {
        public double a { get; set; }
        public double b { get; set; }
        public CRectangular(double a, double b)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
        public override double S() { return a * b; }
        public override double P() { return 2 * (a + b); }
    }
    class zad
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CSquare f1 = new CSquare(5);
            Console.WriteLine("Лицето на квадрата е {0}, а периметъра е {1}.", f1.S(), f1.P());
            CRectangular f2 = new CRectangular(2, 3);
            Console.WriteLine("Лицето на правоъгълника е {0}, а периметъра е {1}.", f2.S(), f2.P());
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

**Second Project**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using zad8;


namespace zad8
{
    class CParallelepiped : CRectangular
    {
        public CParallelepiped(double a, double b, double h) : base(a, b) {
            this.h = h;
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
        double h { get; set; }
        //public CParallelepiped(double h) { this.h = h; }



        public override double SF() { return 2 * (a*b+b*h+h*a); }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Пълната повърхнина на фигурата е {0}",SF());
        }
        public override double V() { return a*b* h; }
        public override string ToString() { return string.Format("Обема на фигурата е {0}", V()); }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string [] args)
        {
            //CParallelepiped f3 = new CParallelepiped(1,2,3);
            //Console.WriteLine("Пълната повърхнина на паралелепипеда е {0}.", f3.SF());
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't the missing `SF` / `V` overrides on `CSquare` / `CRectangle`? add those, and it compiles for me...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577298/program-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-for-an-entry-point

Comment: Note: one of the build options is a switch that tells it *what type* to look for a `Main` method in... if you have *specified* that, but specified it incorrectly: it won't work. Try to change that value - it is the "Startup object" in project properties, on the "Application" tab - or `<StartupObject>` in the csproj

Comment: Post code as part of the question, not on pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your implementation, but the Main method is not one of them.

- You need to implement all abstract members.
- You have two ToString() implementations in `CParallelepiped`
- You probably shouldn't reference a console app from another console app. Use a class library for that instead.

The following code compiles:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using zad8;


namespace zad8
{
    public abstract class CFormulas
    {
        abstract public double S();
        abstract public double P();
        abstract public double SF();
        abstract public double V();
    }
    public class CSquare : CFormulas
    {
        double a { get; set; }
        public CSquare(double a)
        { this.a = a; }
        public override double S() { return a * a; }
        public override double P() { return 4 * a; }
        public override double SF()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override double V()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    public class CRectangular : CFormulas
    {
        public double a { get; set; }
        public double b { get; set; }
        public CRectangular(double a, double b)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
        public override double S() { return a * b; }
        public override double P() { return 2 * (a + b); }
        public override double SF()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override double V()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    class CParallelepiped : CRectangular
    {
        public CParallelepiped(double a, double b, double h) : base(a, b) {
            this.h = h;
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
        double h { get; set; }
        //public CParallelepiped(double h) { this.h = h; }



        public override double SF() { return 2 * (a*b+b*h+h*a); }

        public override double V() { return a*b* h; }
        public override string ToString() { return string.Format("Обема на фигурата е {0}", V()); }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string [] args)
        {
            //CParallelepiped f3 = new CParallelepiped(1,2,3);
            //Console.WriteLine("Пълната повърхнина на паралелепипеда е {0}.", f3.SF());
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
     }
}
```