# C# "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point" for a MSTest project

Tags: c#

I created a project that has a few objects and methods. Call This A1.

I then created another blank in the same directory and added the dependencies A1.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace A1.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class A1Tests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestCar()
        {
          // some testing code etc
          // Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I try and build I get that error "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point" and I'm not even sure how to start debugging.

My main project "A1" has a static main and builds just fine without this MSTest project.

Comment: Hi, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577298/program-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-for-an-entry-point/577318

Comment: Is the test project set as startup project in the solution? Are you trying to run the project from VS or just build?

Comment: Try opening up the project properties of your test project. In the Application tab, check if the Output type is set to Class library. If it is set to Windows Application or Console Application that may cause the error.

Comment: The output was not set to Class Library, thank you for that! This is setup as a blank project from what I remeber in VS.